# AsyncSnapshot rejecting Type Annotation

Tags: flutter, rxdart

I have a `StreamBuilder` that is taking data from my bloc component.

However it keeps rejecting my type annotation `AsyncSnapshot<List<int>> snapshot` and only accepts dynamic as a type `AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot`. Yet in the examples i've viewed they do have type annotaions with no complaints.

Here is my stream creation.

```
Widget buildList(StoriesBloc bloc) {
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: bloc.topIds,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<int>> snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Text("Still Waiting for Ids to fetch");
    }

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
        return Text('${snapshot.data[index]}');
      },
    );
  },
);
```

}

Here is the VSCode error generated.
[image: VSCode Error]

What could i be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my `bloc.topIds` result type was not of type `List<int>`.

`Observable<List> get topIds => _topIds.stream;`

So i simply changed it to fulfill the required type.

`Observable<List<int>> get topIds => _topIds.stream;`

And that fixed the issue. Hope it helps someone else.